# inserting record in junction table asp.net MVC 4 Entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity framework 6 in my asp.net MVC 4 application. I have two tables with many to many reationship profiles and profilepositions. I created a junction table with ids of both. I am using code first approach. How can I insert record in this table ? Do I need to create virtual properties in both tables for junction table or what.

```
 public class Profile
    {
       public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
       // other properties
    }

public class Account
    {
        public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
        // other properties

    }

// junction table
 public class AccountConnection
    {
       public int AccountID { get; set; }
       public int ProfileID { get; set; }
    }
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would build the tables like this:

```
public class Profile
{
   public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

   // other properties
}

Public class Account
{
    public Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    // other properties

}
```

To add records to either tables you just use Profile.Accounts.Add( 'Account Model' ) and Account.Profiles.Add( 'Profile Model' )

The junction table is created automatically

Comment: what if the juntion tablehas more than just the 2 primary keys? what ifyou need to actually create another table?